# Error: "Attempted to access ReactWrapper::node, which was previously a private property" when using enzyme 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have the following lines in my test (using react and enzyme):

```
const input = mount(<MyComponent/>).find('input').node;
input.focus();
input.select();
```

I have upgraded enzyme from v2 to v3, and now it throws the following error:

> Attempted to access ReactWrapper::node, which was previously a private
>   property on
>               Enzyme ReactWrapper instances, but is no longer and should not be relied upon.
>               Consider using the getElement() method instead.

However, when I use `getElement()` like suggested in the error, like so:

`const input = mount(<MyComponent/>).find('input').getElement();`

The resulting object doesn't have the functions that were in the original `.node`:

> TypeError: (0 , _enzyme.mount)(...).find(...).getElement(...).focus is
>   not a function
>
> TypeError: (0 , _enzyme.mount)(...).find(...).getElement(...).select
>   is not a function

What should I use instead of `.node` and `.getElement()` to make this code work in enzyme 3?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `.node` you should use `.instance()` or `.getDOMNode()`, depends if you used the result as a ReactElement or DOMComponent.

Comment: also adding that you can replace ```.nodes[0]``` with ```.instance()```